# Why do I have a picture on my contact list of a iPhone number I wrote down?

Tags: ios

I wrote down someone's phone number on my iPhone. He also had an iPhone. However, we are not connected in any way. Example: no social media, he hasn't sent me a message, no email, etc. I know that the iPhone pulls pictures from many places but in this case, we don't have anything in common.

How would his picture appear on my phone under his contact name?

Comment: Maybe it’s something described here: https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/share-your-name-and-photo-ichta791c41e/mac

Comment: Thank you Aivar Paailber but from what I read, the other person needs to agree with this and didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any contact photo from the contacts app. It’s going to be hard for us to guess your setup without sitting shoulder to shoulder and reviewing all the places you could have added an account. The likely culprit is the other person chose to share that image with you when asked by Apple permission to share their name and icon. They may not be aware this happens or mistakenly tapped the allow button while they were putting the phone in their pocket. It’s a one tap to share situation in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I was under the impression that I have to accept when they decide to "share their name and icon". Is that correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know how the receive side is engineered @DeivydAzevedo I never have to accept it. Maybe you are thinking if you add that image to your contacts as opposed to passively draw what the person sent you? Apple describes the consent on changing address book - not about displaying pixels on your screen - “ your contacts still need to agree to update your name and photo in your contact card in the Contacts app”  https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/share-your-name-and-photo-ichta791c41e/mac